# Determine and return the Month name based on reading file with dates as numbers(ie. 12/03/04) in Java

Tags: java

I need to read a file which contains dates in this format: MM/DD/YY

Then take the month number 1-12, and convert to the months name.

I know how to read the file and I think that I should use a for loop with an if loop inside it like:

for(i = 1, i < 13, i++)

if( i = fileDate)
      Etc.

I just don't know what to do after this. Once I get the month number, how would I turn it into the month name?

Comment: Also per the assignment, I have to use string format for the dates

Comment: Use a SimpleDateFormat with the right pattern to parse the string to a Date. Use another SimpleDateFormat with the right pattern to format the Date as a String. The javadoc is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get month name using [DateFormatSymbols.getMonths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths%28%29) method as below:

```
int month = 11;//read month
System.out.println(new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[month - 1]);//-1 as array starts from 0
Output:
November
```

Alternatively, if you want your own implementation, then you could define your own enum or array (because you have fixed months which wont change ever) and can access by index or ordinal like:

```
enum MONTHS {
    JANUARY, FEBRAURY...
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int month = 2;// read month
    System.out.println(MONTHS.values()[month - 1]);//values will convert enum to array and then you could access month name from index
}
 Output:
 FEBRAURY
```